# error: subprocess-exited-with-error × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install pybraille in anaconda promt/comand prompt
However, I am having the following error message

```
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda_2024>pip install pybraille
Collecting pybraille
  Using cached pybraille-1.0.0.tar.gz (3.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-czxsx3rh\pybraille_12011c4642ce4e0090b4d59777d3ddcd\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          long_description = rd.read()
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 406: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

C:\Users\Admin\anaconda_2024>
```

Things I have tried to solve it : upgrade pip, pip install pybraille--pre,pip install setup tools --upgrade wheel,pip install pybraille --no-build-isolation,pip install —upgrade setuptools.I have also used the forge command in conda to instsll it. But none of them worked for me. Is there any other way i can solve this problem? thannk you
My python version is 3.11.7